# Updating cache on Apollo Client

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client

I'm using Apollo Dev Tools for Chrome and I can't seem to understand how to update the cache.

1. The cache is the same after every query even though it's rendering the correct data.
2. I'm developing a CRUD app and on a delete I want the page to show the changes made on the server. After executing a mutation that deletes an item in a DB I also want to delete this item from the cache.

   ```
   // mutation
   const DELETE_ELEMENT_MUTATION = gql`
     mutation DELETE_ELEMENT_MUTATION($id: String!) {
       deleteElement(id: $id)
     }
   `;

   // update cache
   update = (cache, payload) => {
     const data = cache.readQuery({query: queryAllElements});
     const result = data.allElements.filter(element => {
       const elementId = script._id;
       const compareId = JSON.parse(payload.data.deleteElement).id;

       return elementId !== compareId;
     });

     cache.writeQuery({query: queryAllElements, data: result});
   };

   <Mutation
     mutation={DELETE_ELEMENT_MUTATION}
     variables={{id: id}}
     update={this.update}
   >
     {(deleteElement) => (
       <Icon
         onClick={() => {
           deleteElement();
         }}
       />
     )}
   </Mutation>
   ```

After update the cache is not updating.

Edit: changed

```
cache.writeQuery({query: getAllElements, data: result}); 
// to 
cache.writeQuery({query: queryAllElements, data: result});
```

Comment: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/3909

Comment: I'll try to do what is described in the issue. Meanwhile, I didn't think it's important at the time of writing the question by my <Mutation /> is a return from a <Query /> and was thinking maybe that's causing the problem?

Comment: Your read query is using "queryAllElements" and your write query is using "getAllElements"

Comment: My bad, I unintentionally did this when shrinking down the code to the smallest meaningful example. It's queryAllElements on both lines.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. Turns out I was updating the wrong key in the cache.

[solution](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/4079)